# Why does my MySQL instance think "'ī" and "i" are equal characters?

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm running into uniqueness constraint problems in MySQL. I have two different characters:

- `ī` which is ASCII decimal 299
- `i` which is ASCII decimal 109

Why does MySQL see these as equal? When I run the following:

```
SELECT STRCMP('ī', 'i')
```

I get a return value of `0`.

Per request, here is some information about my environment:

```
mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8mb4                  | utf8mb4_unicode_ci   |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Please show your table definition.

Comment: This query is independent of a table. Is there a different definition I can provide?

Comment: _"This query is independent of a table"_ -> http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/ - There's character sets / collation at the table and database levels.

Comment: @John can you clarify what query of information you'd like me to provide?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely familiar with how to retrieve this information, but if you can find out the character set and collation settings for your database and include them in the question, that should go a long way towards answering it, I imagine.

Comment: Added the information to the OP

Comment: The `_ci` at the end of the collation means that it's case-insensitive. I think that also means it's insensitive to accents.

Comment: The "Answer Section" text alongside the answer section means it's for answers. I think that also means you're not supposed to put answers in the comments section.

Comment: ASCII does not go to 299.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database defaults to collating *case insensitively*: that is the `ci` part at the end of `@@collation_database`. In this collation, for most languages, diacritic marks are folded. From the docs:

> To further illustrate, the following equalities hold in both utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci (for the effect of this in comparisons or searches, see Section 10.8.6, “Examples of the Effect of Collation”):
>
> Ä = A
>   Ö = O
>   Ü = U

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Unless you have founded reasons for doing so, I would suggest changing this default.

Answer (score 3):

Characters are equal if they are defined as being equal in the current collation.

Strings have a character set and collation defined. If the string comes from a table, the table or the column defines the collation.

If the string is a literal you use in an SQL expression (like your example), the collation of a string defaults to the session value for the MySQL options `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection`.

You can override the session values for a given string literal by using the `COLLATE` clause:

```
mysql> SELECT STRCMP('ī', 'i' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin);
+---------------------------------------+
| STRCMP('ī', 'i' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin)  |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-introducer.html